# How to recursively replace typescript primitives with a parameterized type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-utility

`type` or `interface` could both work.

```js
interface example {
  s: string;
  o: {
    t: string;
    arrn: number[];
    arr: {
      u: string;
    }[];
};
```

Would transform to

```js
interface transformed {
  s: {
    onChange: (v: string) => void;
  };
  o: {
    t: {
      onChange: (v: string) => void;
    };
    arrn: {
      onChange: (v: number) => void;
    }[];
    arr: {
      u: {
        onChange: (v: number) => void;
      };
    }[];
};
```

#### Is this possible?

What is the direction to do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following type satisfies what you describe:

```
interface example {
  s: string;
  o: {
    t: string;
    arrn: number[];
    arr: {
      u: string;
    }[];
  };
}

type ReplacePrimitives<T> = T extends Record<any, any>
  ? { [K in keyof T]: ReplacePrimitives<T[K]> }
  : { onChange: (value: T) => void };

type transformed = ReplacePrimitives<example>;
```

It recursively replaces all primitive values with the `onChange` object you describe, leaving records and array structures in place.

Comment: Haha yeah, wish there was some indication on SO like "someone is currently answering this" :)

Comment: Oh good this was easier than I expected! I forgot arrays and objects were both records. Thank you - I can't assign 2 answer correct :P

Answer (score 1):

```ts
type Transform<T> = T extends object
  // T is an object (including an array), so transform each property
  ? {[K in keyof T]: Transform<T[K]>}
  // T is a primitive, so do the transformation
  : {onchange: (v: T) => void};

type transformed = Transform<example>
```

This works as expected for tuples and arrays as well:

```ts
// {onchange: (v: string) => void}[]
type ArrayTest = Transform<string[]>;
// readonly {onchange: (v: string) => void}[]
type ReadonlyArrayTest = Transform<readonly string[]>;
/* [
  {onchange: (v: string) => void},
  {onchange: (v: number) => void},
  ...{onchange: (v: boolean) => void}[],
] */
type TupleTest = Transform<[string, number, ...boolean[]]>;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAggDzgWwA4BsUDeAUMsgM4Bc5YUoA5gNwnID2VxppYVZN9TnZHChQQVEAFdMAI2gBtALoDOwqO2aCJPPiEYbkAX0XKDRA0yJgAnthQAVKHBBkYLKJgA8dgHzIAvMh2qGiQIAAmZKzSAFYQCGDIAPzIBHIA0sigyADWEFYsMIEKVA5OLm6edukK3gbI7CwgCAAWTnQQVAAUAG4lAJT+vt0swGHmRJY2KDRlru4QYf6Bjs5znuhYeBDeFta2yACCInBWdhC8S6WrFR68tLqKO5P7AEoQcGGNuFZHjqfnCQCV3K7g8UHenxA32o9zojyYe3sEi2ZwuQJWIM8cju9AANMhJDJoPiAHRk6QsFj4JyKGq7KaBAGXDFrDwcZDYWiYYBgYDdDoEqSyKDKMDI-BUbE6Oj4wnCpTMcEfL4-Y5WKhKyHQuXyBWkEAAhbsOAaiEq5BS2FKZDScRC6AMZAIdhhSUUqnvECy+1QBQGcYGJ5AA)